# How to call lat/long from a seperate file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a v3api google map that includes optional map polygons the user can choose to display or not.

To display the shapes in the old api I would have javascript code like so:

```
function rmx_bounds(){
var myShapeCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(48.2767,-81.728),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.2786,-80.811),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.7104,-81.727),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.2767,-81.728)
];

var myShape;
myShape = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: myShapeCoords,
strokeColor: "##f33f00",
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWeight: 3,
fillColor: "#9900CC",
fillOpacity: 0.2
});

myShape.setMap(map);
}
```

However 'myShape' can have hundreds of coordinates and there can be dozens of shapes

rather than stuff my file with thousands of lines, can i somehow put them in a separate file and call it from the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `myShapeCoords` in a seperate `JavaScript` file and include it as `<script src="myCoordinates.js" type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the data to a file in JSON format, and load the file on demand.
To process the JSON file you may use straightforward (but unsafe sometimes) approach:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

Or use jQuery, or use any JSON library.